# If a struct cannot inherit another class or struct, why does Int32 have a ToString() method?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, struct

```
int a = 2;

Console.WriteLine(a.ToString()); // displays 2

// definition of ToString() here - public override string ToString();
```

Now, here are some of my understandings:

1. All the classes in .net get a `ToString()` method, which is inherited from the `Object` class.
2. A structure cannot be derived from a Class or another struct. `int` is a structure of type `Int32`, which  gets a couple of `ToString()` [With Parameters] methods from the Interfaces which it implements.
3. There is also a `ToString()` [without params] function in struct `Int32`

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tostring.aspx,

> struct Int32 overrides ValueType.ToString() method

If a struct cannot inherit some class or struct, can you please explain how this `ToString()` method is available for `Int32`?

Comment: all types derive from Object somehow. int derive from ValueType which derive from Object. Your assumption 2 is wrong. http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/chap13_0321169514/elementLinks/13fig02.gif

Comment: @0lukasz0 [Not *everything* derives from object](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx).

Comment: "struct Int32 overrides ValueType.ToString() method" answers your own question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> If a struct cannot inherit some class or struct,

This isn't true.  All structs (and the built-in value types, like `System.Int32`, `System.Single`, etc) always implicitly inherit from [`System.ValueType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx) (which, in turn, inherits from `System.Object`).

However, you can't make a struct that inherits from *anything else*.

This is clearly spelled out in the C# language spec, 4.1.1:

> 4.1.1 The System.ValueType type
>
> All value types implicitly inherit from the class System.ValueType, which, in turn, inherits from class object. It is not possible for any type to derive from a value type, and value types are thus implicitly sealed (§10.1.1.2).

Then, later (4.1.3) struct is explicitly defined to be a value type:

> 4.1.3 Struct types
>
> A struct type is a value type that can declare constants, fields, methods, properties, indexers, operators, instance constructors, static constructors, and nested types.

Comment: So if i am creating a new custom struct i cannot inherit from any other class, but the existing struct's are inherited from ValueType? Can u confirm?

Comment: @robot *All* structs inherit from `ValueType`, even ones you create, even if you don't explicitly state that it inherits from ValueType (which you couldn't do even if you wanted to).

Comment: @robot That's exactly right - struct will always inherit from ValueType, but never from anything else.

Comment: And if you write your own **enum**, it will derive from `System.Enum` which derives from `System.ValueType`, but you are not allowed to specify the base class for a struct or an enum; they must be "automatic". If you write your enum like `public enum Color : short { ... }`, then `short` is **not** the base type. It's the "underlying" integral type.

Answer (score 1):

Every definition of a type derived from ValueType actually defines two distinct kinds of things in the runtime: a type of heap object (which derives from `ValueType` and in turn from `Object`, and which contains embedded type information), and a type of storage location (which doesn't contain any embedded type information, but instead requires that code which uses it must have some other means of knowing what it is).  An instance of the heap object type contains a field of the storage-location type, and code which attempts to access `this` will access that field.  If a value type is cast implicitly or explicitly to a storage location of reference type, the system will create a new heap object with the appropriate type and copy all public and private fields of the value-type to corresponding fields within the heap object.  If a heap object is cast to a value-type storage location, all public and private fields from the heap object will be copied to the value-type storage location.

If an attempt is made to use any `Object` or interface method on a heap object of a value type, the method will be called just like any other heap-object method.  If the attempt is made on a value-type storage location, for any method other than `GetType`, the compiler will generate a special "constrained" opcode which informs the runtime of the type of the storage location and instructs the Runtime to call the address of the method appropriate to that type.  Since the compiler will have the storage location type available, and the run-time can use that to find the appropriate method, the appropriate method can be invoked directly on the storage location, without having to create a new heap object first.  `GetType` is the one notable exception; since it works by examining the type information embedded within an object, it can only work on things that have embedded type information.  Consequently, its argument will be converted to the heap-object form before the call; `GetType` will then be able to examine the embedded type information of that heap object.

Comment: Were you trying to avoid using the term *boxing* (or any variation thereof)?

Comment: @BenVoigt: I would not expect that invoking `ToString` on an `Int32` would involve boxing [it could be defined in such a fashion as to require boxing, but I can't think why it would be].  It might have been good to mention that the process of converting an object to its heap-object form is called boxing, but I wasn't sure how and where best to say that without distracting from the main point, which is that such a process isn't necessary when calling `Int32.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

`Int32` implements [`IFormattable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.aspx), which defines the `ToString` method

Comment: IFormattable defines a parameterized ToString method, not the parameterless ToString method that the OP is asking about.