# Can a structure inherit from a class in .NET?

Tags: class, inheritance, struct

I am confused about inheritance in .NET and here is why.

I was previously of the understanding that a structure cannot inherit from a class in .NET, so for example, the following won't compile:

```
struct MyStruct : MyClass
{

}
```

But today I read that integers (and other value types) are structs and not objects and they inherit from the [ValueType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx) class. The ValueType class inherits from [System.Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) and its purpose is to override certain methods in [System.Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) to make these methods suitable for Value Types.

So what's the deal? Can a structure inherit from a class in .NET, can it not or can it only in certain circumstances?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727151/if-a-struct-cannot-inherit-another-class-or-struct-why-does-int32-have-a-tostri

Comment: @Jake1164 Yes actually, this guy is basically asking the same question I am! My mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the guts of .net, the definition for a struct containing certain members is the same as a definition for a class which those same fields and members, and which inherits from `System.ValueType`.  Note that compilers will not allow one to declare a `class` which inherits `ValueType`, but when one declares a `struct`, the compiler, "behind the scenes" declares a class which does.

What makes value types special in .net is the way the run-time allocates storage locations (variables, fields, parameters, etc.)  When a storage location of a type not inheriting from `ValueType` is declared, the runtime will allocate space for a heap object reference.  By contrast, when a storage location of a type inheriting from `ValueType` is declared, the runtime will allocate space for all the public and private fields of that type.  For a type like `int`, the system allocates a private field which is of a special primitive type, outside the normal type system.

Note that a storage location of a value type doesn't really hold an instance of that type; instead *is* an instance of that type, and *holds* all of the fields of that type.  A statement like `struct1 = struct2` does not replace the value-type instance `struct1` with the instance `struct2`.  Instead, it copies all of the fields from `struct2` over the corresponding fields in `struct1`.  Likewise if a value-type storage location is passed as a method to a procedure without using the `ref` keyword, what is passed is not the struct instance itself, but rather the contents of its fields.

If it is necessary to copy a value-type storage location to a one of type not derived from `ValueType` (e.g. `Object` or `IComparable`), the system will create a new heap-object instance of the value type, copy all the fields from the value type to that new instancen and store a reference to that new instance in the target storage location.  This process is called "boxing".  Most compilers will do this implicitly, thus attempting to behave as though a value type storage location holds an object which derives from `ValueType`.  It's important to note, though, that this is an illusion.  If type `X` derives from `Y`, one has an `X` named `xx` and a `Y` named `yy`, and one performs `xx = yy`, such a statement should cause `xx` and `yy` to refer to the same object instance.  That will happen if `xx` and `yy` are types not derived from `ValueType`, even if `yy` holds an instance of something derived from `ValueType`.  It will not happen, however, if `xx` and/or `yy` derives from `ValueType`.  In that case, the system will copy fields from one instance to another (possibly new) instance.